# When should -c or -o GCC options be used in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am using a Makefile to compile my cpp files and header files. But what I don't fully understand is the difference between -o and -c while compiling. 
I know -o creates an object file and normally we write
   "g++ -o compile demo.cpp" 
to compile a program demo.cpp.
But when compiling a program that has many classes, why are we using
    "g++ -c class.cpp"
and not -o like we normally do. Here's a sample Makefile. Thanks a lot for helping me out!

```
all:compile

compile: demo.cpp class.o
    g++ -o compile demo.cpp class.o
class.o: class.h class.cpp
    g++ -c class.cpp
```

Comment: `-o` simply means `output name`. `-c` means `compile only, don't link`. A more complete (non default) version of your example might say `g++ -c class.cpp -o class.o`.

Comment: First of all check docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... why are we using `g++ -c class.cpp` ..."*

As from [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) (emphasis mine):

> -c
>   Compile or assemble the source files, **but do not link**. The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.
>   By default, the object file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, ‘.s’, etc., with ‘.o’.
>
> Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are ignored.

and

> -o *file*
>   Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether **it be an executable file**, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>   If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

`-c` is used to ensure, that `class.o` is compiled as an object file, that can be linked from the later applied rule for the `compile` target.

As the wanted `compile` target is an executable, `-o` is used, to make sure that linkage is done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great explanation